# Tengo un erro del tipo KeyError: 'carro'

Tags: django, python-3.7

#todo esto se encuentra dentro de un content_processor y ya esta registrado en el settings.py
def importe_total_carro(request):
Total=0
if key, value in
request.session['carro'].items():
Total= Total+(float(value['precio'])*value['cantidad'])
return {'importe_total_carro':Total}

Comment: Replantea la pregunta, tal como se encuentra no mas explicas algo sin mostrar donde y como ocurre el error

Answer (score 0):

Lo mas probable es que el key 'carro' aun no existe en tu sesión, antes de iterarlo primero cerciórate que ya exista, puedes hacerlo de esta manera:

```
def importe_total_carro(request): 
    Total=0 

    if 'carro' in request.session:
        # Verificar que ya exista 'carro' en la sesion

        if key, value in request.session['carro'].items():
            Total= Total+(float(value['precio'])*value['cantidad']) 
            return {'importe_total_carro':Total}

    # Regresa Total=0 si el key 'carro' no existe en la sesión
    # Aqui manejarlo como mejor te convenga
    return Total
```